# how to set progress bar unvisible, and when text is writing in my autocomplete to become visible again.android

Tags: android, textview, android-progressbar

i have implemented a textwatcher so when i am writing something i want my progress bar to become visible( and ofcourse how to make it unvisible at onCreate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to hide a control such as a ProgressBar in Android use the setVisibility() method like that:

```
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   // To set it visible
```

and:

```
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // To set it invisible
```

So just set it to View.INVISIBLE inside your Activity onCreate() method, then set it to View.VISIBLE when you need it to be visible.